# How to set BigPictureStyle on Web Push Notifications?

Tags: service-worker, web-push, progressive-web-apps, web-notifications

In my native app I send [BigPictureStyle notifications](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.BigPictureStyle.html) and want to do the same on the web.

I have built a Progressive Web App and am using service worker-based web push notifications, but can't find a way to show BigPictureStyle notifications to my Android users. Is this possible with the [Notifications API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification)? Am I just missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Currently Notification API is not support BigPicture yet but is in Github issue already https://github.com/whatwg/notifications/issues/79